# How to capture an alert box using java after executing a http request?

Tags: java

I have implemented a java program which executes a http request. Now if this request were to give an alert box, how can I capture it?
The code is as below

`String url= "http://www.quettamotors.pk/car_details.php?id=(script)alert(1)(/script)";` `//added the round brackets as it is not allowing angular brackets.`

```
URL myurl= new URL(url);

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll , FileProtocolHandler " + myurl);
```

Help please!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
String query = myurl.getQuery();
```

It will return you **id=(script)alert(1)(/script)** as *String*. Now you can split it by **=**;

Comment: In the same way how can I input data to a input box in a web page?

Comment: In web page you can use javascript to set the value in text field.

Answer (score 0):

Provide an [alert handler to a WebEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#setOnAlert%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29).

The following is Java 8 code which will log JavaScript alert messages to the console:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AlertReporter extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        final WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load(
            "http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert"
        );
        webView.getEngine().setOnAlert(
            event -> System.out.println(event.getData())
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(webView));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```